# How to make a search field to insert the result in a LazyColumn

Tags: android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How to make a search field to insert the result in a LazyColumn
My code:

```
 @Composable
    private fun SearchTopBar(){
        TopAppBar(title={  },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { onBackPressed() }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = stringResource(
                                id = R.string.back
                        ),tint= colorResource(id = R.color.black) )
                    }

                    
                },
                contentColor = Color.White,
                backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.pastel_green),
                actions = {
                    TextField()
                }
        )
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Main(){
        Scaffold(topBar={SearchTopBar()},content={})
    }
```

Dynamically change the content the search that comes from the api

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce a `ViewModel` with two states:

- `val query: StateFlow<String>`
- `val items: StateFlow<T>`

Then use the [stateHoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) pattern with the `value`, `onValueChanged` to modify your query.

Your `items` should observe your `query` in the `viewModel` and update the `items`.

And you could again observe the result `items` in your **Composable** with `viewModel.items.collectAsState()`

See [this example](https://github.com/mitchtabian/MVVMRecipeApp/blob/searchview-toolbar/app/src/main/java/com/codingwithmitch/mvvmrecipeapp/presentation/ui/recipe_list/RecipeListFragment.kt) for more information

Comment: can't you use retrofit to call the api?

Comment: @RafaelSouze, yes you can, so you could call a retrofit `onEach{ }` emission of the `query`, and in the result update the items. I'd suggest to also do a `debounce()` before the `onEach` so that you don't trigger too many requests

Comment: using MutableLiveData and LiveData in my MainViewModel with class data using "com.squareup.moshi.Json" and Retrofit for the api is a good idea